# Error BC30829 'Get' statements are no longer supported - Converting from vb6 to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I am converting a project from vb6 to vb.net.
I converted most of the part but stuck on a line.

VB6 code :

```
    Do While Not EOF(FileO)
        Get #FileO, , ByteBuffer
        If Loc(FileO) < LOF(FileO) Then
            ByteCounter = ByteCounter + 64
        End If
    Loop
```

VB.NET Code :

```
  Do While Not EOF(FileO)
            Get(#FileO, , ByteBuffer) '----------> PROBLEM HERE
            If Loc(FileO) < LOF(FileO) Then
                ByteCounter = ByteCounter + 64
            End If
        Loop
```

I am getting problem over the get statement.
`Get(#FileO, , ByteBuffer)`

Error I am facing is :

> Error  BC30829 'Get' statements are no longer supported. File I/O functionality is available in the 'Microsoft.VisualBasic' namespace.

What is replacement for GET statement?? How to apply?
Thanx :)

Comment: Take a look for the reference: [BC30829 Get statement deprecation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30829). You should use `System.IO` for file operations, e.g. `ReadAllLines`, `ReadAllBytes`, etc.

Comment: Ideally, the code should be reworked to use System.IO. Pursuant to an answer based on System.IO, it would be helpful if you provided a full code sample (replete with variable definitions).

Comment: Voting to reopen. The C# equivalent is NOT the VB.net equivalent.  And the problems are not equivalent problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Option Explicit On

 Imports System
 Imports System.IO

 Module Module1
     Sub Main()
         Dim ByteBuffer As Byte()

         Using myFile As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(File.Open("TESTFILE.BIN", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
             While myFile.BaseStream.Position < myFile.BaseStream.Length
                 ByteBuffer = myFile.ReadBytes(64)
             End While

             myFile.Close()
         End Using
     End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

As a jump start - you should use your ide and the object browser to see what you can get from this:

```
// make sure the read buffer is big enough
string testReadData = "".PadRight(128);
int filenumber = VB6FileSystem.FreeFile();
VB6FileSystem.FileOpen(filenumber, @"c:\temp\test.dat", VB.OpenMode.Random, RecordLength: 128);
// Write some test data ....
VB6FileSystem.FilePut(filenumber, "Testdaten 1", 1, true);
VB6FileSystem.FilePut(filenumber, "Testdaten 4", 4, true);
VB6FileSystem.FilePut(filenumber, "Testdaten 14", 14, true);
// Read some data ...
VB6FileSystem.FileGet(filenumber, ref testReadData, 14, true);
VB6FileSystem.FileClose(filenumber);
```

I think, you can grasp it

Comment: Although I agree with the "reworking" approach, I would like to know what was wrong with my answer - I see it as the answer to the original post (how to replace GET from VB6 in .NET).

Comment: Probably the fact that your examples are all FilePut while the question was about Get...

Comment: Ok, I assumed every developer will be able to "grasp the concept" and see how it works. But I agree, thats an useful hint.

Comment: @jmorene: Following your hint, I improved the answer